# Read only web content of given URL and strip HTML and javaScript tag out of it - C# regex expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex, html-parsing

I have two class one which build response stream and string of web content of given url and another class to strip html tags using regex expression but it not completely stripping contents down. what I want is just content from web page so I want to ignore javaScript code, html and any other tag.

2nd part; I want to introduce another class which just read url from web content

```
 public void processURL()
   {
       // used to build entire input
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

       // used on each read operation
       byte[] buf = new byte[8192];

       HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)
           WebRequest.Create("http://www.uwl.ac.uk/why-uwl");

       HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

       // we will read data via the response stream
       Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
       string tempString = null;
       int count = 0;

       do
       {
           count = resStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);

           if (count != 0)
           {
               tempString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, count);
               sb.Append(tempString);
           }
       }
       while (count > 0); // any more data to read?
       Console.WriteLine(".............................");
       Console.WriteLine(StripTagsRegex(sb.ToString()));
   }

   public static string StripTagsRegex(string source)
   {
       return Regex.Replace(source, "<.*?>", string.Empty);
   }
```

Comment: You do realize that you will loose all line brakes and formatting, right?

Answer (score 1):

I would not suggest to use regular expressions for parsing HTML. Use some HTML-parsing library instead. E.g. [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack). You can easily select all text nodes from given html:

```
string html;
// get html
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
var textNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()");
```

Now you can grab inner text of each node

```
var pageText = string.Join(" ", textNodes.Select(n => n.InnerText.Trim()));
```

---

Downloading html:

```
string html;

using(var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
using(var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
    html = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Or more simple

```
var client = new WebClient();
string html = client.DownloadString("http://www.uwl.ac.uk/why-uwl");
```

Comment: You can get the whole Web page with HtmlAgilityPack, too: `var webGet = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
            var doc = webGet.Load(url);`

Comment: I still am getting all javaScript and other tags in using var pageText  = string.Join(" ", textNodes.Select(n => n.InnerText.Trim()));

Comment: no this is not working! HtmlAgilityPack is giving me more tags and javascript then the regex expression